# Select Box height/width with Bootstrap does not match height of other form input boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form that I'm making with Bootstrap. The inputs are just text boxes, but there is one `select box`. I've tried using the `input-xs` and `input-mini` classes but the height of the `select box` does not match the height or width of the other input boxes and does not seem to change. Is this an incorrect class issue or is there something else going on?

I've created a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/c85uaqmt/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make the input's `form-control` too. Also, the markup is missing a closing DIV tag.

`<input class="form-control" id="Name" name="Name" type="text" placeholder="">`

http://bootply.com/vpTL7MHHZG

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the class "input-group"

```
 <div class="form-group input-group">
    <label for="sel1">Select list:</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="select" placeholder="">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
    </select>
```